# In a Typescript declaration file, how to specify that a class extends an instance of another class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototypal-inheritance

I have a vanilla JS project that I would like to benefit from (and eventually migrate to) typescript. I'm starting by writing some declaration files.

The javascript class I'm trying to create a declaration for extends instances of another class like so:

```js
class Parent {}
const ParentInstance = () => class extends Parent {}
const ChildInstance = (InstanceParent) => class extends InstanceParent {}
class Thing {
  constructor () {
    this.ParentInstance = ParentInstance()
    this.Child = ChildInstance(this.ParentInstance)
  }
}

let thing1 = new Thing()
let thing2 = new Thing()
let childOf1 = new thing1.Child()

childOf1 instanceof thing1.Child // true
childOf1 instanceof thing2.Child // false
```

The result is that `c` is an instance of `Child` *such that* its prototype chain is strictly tied to a specific instance of `Thing`. How can I talk about this kind of prototypal inheritance in Typescript?

```js
declare class Thing {
  Child: Child<?instance constructor?>
}
```

---

[Link to playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=57#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3tAvgKGAHsUIN5l0BJEtMFYJaAXmgB4AVaJADzVQBMY7ABYBLFAHMAfAAo0ALmjsAlMynRQkGDz4pBcRKgzY0Yyc2gZ8RGtADCYkP2qk6DCxy68BQs9JkutPRI5EaKKEgA7tAyqkzqJn6KnDhx6ppQXrr6gW4hhuhYuATgmSLiElh40DVwlOFRMWlFphXJuBahVDR5cmIQytW1DqJODdGxai1JlgCeAA5IhABmSn44FiNOucF9ohAAdLCUg-h4IEgYrZIAjBYR0eWSseeXln4ATPeNTxIvFxhgI5+AB5ZZ3FgPd4VG4HLb8F4EYFgu7iVzBFbQ25w4HQAD0eMsCAArkgkaNQeDoGiggxMdcJB8cRT8YTlmAQBAya9Acjll9IY0GUz4bEANx4clOMECjR8m5i1lcBAIQgIACENTwBKUC0YAHIAEQMm6G-XUmAoQgYLSiCQoMAAIwulkIc0W0CNwrNByAA) how to define `T` here?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  To keep track of instances in the type system you'd need [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) which are not part of TypeScript.  Perhaps you can simulate this, though... [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) can be used to give dependent-type-like behavior. What do you think about `Thing`'s constructor requiring an "id" string to distinguish instances from each other?

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3tAvgKGAHsUIN5l0BJEtMFYJaAXmgB4BpaJADzVQBMYpBAEsUAcwB8ACgDWALmjsAlM0nRQkGDz4pBcRKgzYR-ZtFm4CxUtADCACxEh+1UnQbmOXXgKFpRCRk3WnokciNFFCQAd2hpVSZ1E35FThxE9U0oH119EI9ww3QsK2yYABUnCW8dP2hhMSksPGg2gwo0ArDzCKoaQuk0JwgAOlNlAG5W9sdnMxY5l26GIZHRvq6BsOUZtqIaBABXYDRCBGkAByOAIxARYGhTNNVsfHw8ECQMYaaARnM0TiVSa0gARL8JH8wbsvj9quIAEyA2LQEEScGQpEwz7fDROFwAeQAZgCWEDoFi-qMlvwEngCAT+CSAWJ3GFCMTKQjqbToAB6fmU45IRnzFlPbYMTncpqImlMgVC4lgEAQUW4jDAJkk5Hk1FY+W0hLTMVE4l6-Hi0mTJVcBAIc4AQjaeEFaIAnpdGAByCE8sE+p4wFCEDBaETiFBgO6MM6Ur2+-1ywOjIA)?

Comment: Hmm, that's very interesting. Could your solution be adapted to work with an instance of Thing instead of an instance of String? From the docs on string literal types, I get the impression it's pretty special so the answer will be no. But I just want to check. I'll update with a link to a playground that seems very close (since the link is too long to paste here).

Comment: I ask because in my specific case I'm already passing that instance in and I need them to be more unique than just a string can provide.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it. I'm not sure how a string can be less unique than your instances; there are virtually an infinite number of possible string literals. If you're saying you can't expect to come up with new string literals for each call to `new Thing`, which is a reasonable objection, and that you want each `new Thing()` call to *automatically* generate a new type, that doesn't seem possible. TS only gives you a few handles for generating new types from code and `new Thing` doesn't really let you grab any of them. Everything I've tried has serious flaws compared to my previous suggestion.

Comment: Right then, it seems I can get pretty close but not quite there as things are. As to my complaint about string 'uniqueness,' you're absolutely right, there are plenty of strings out there. I should have said that I need something more run-timey. I wouldn't want to be able to say a = new Thing("a") and b = new Thing("a") and have those treated the same.